# Detect if a child control has a viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, code-behind

I have a Parent View that contains a ContentControl with the following declaration:

```
   <ContentControl x:Name="AppView" Content="{Binding ApplicationView }"/>
```

where ApplicationView is defined in the view code-behind as:

```
    private object _applicationView;
    public object ApplicationView
    {
        get { return _applicationView; }

        set
        {
            _applicationView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Different child views (UserControls) can be assigned to ApplicationView, and elsewhere in the parent view there are bindings to two child control properties; Help and Movie.  The child controls don't have viewmodels, and therefore, child control properties are defined in the child view code-behind.

I would like to use the same parent window with some additional child views (UserControl) but these child views have viewmodels (containing Help and Movie properties) which would require changing the parent view Help and Movie binding declarations.

My question is, is there a way to detect whether a child view (UserControl) has an associated view model?

Comment: check _applicationView DataContext: it can be null or not null

Comment: Why not bind to a property of your parent viewmodel? Or template out that content using viewmodel first? Euther way, uou know what the datacontext is from within your parent viewmodel.